# ［Core Plot］How to change CPTTextStyle.color's value?

Tags: core-plot

I'm working with core plot . When I tried to customize the CPTTextStyle.color's value I found that it's readonly ! Who can tell me how could I change the color property's value ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `CPTMutableTextStyle`. Core Plot follows the common Cocoa convention of mutable and immutable versions of some classes. Line styles, shadows, and plot ranges also follow this pattern.